# FetchError: request to http://localhost:3000/api/projects failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000 (Express/Next.Js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, next.js

I have an API route which upon request gets me the data I want when the Project page (component) is loaded as shown below.

[http://localhost:3000/api/projects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/biVL5.png)

When I load the page where I request for that data inside `getInitialProps()` within `pages/projects.js` it shows data coming through which is what I want as shown below, so far so good.

[console logs data coming through from custom express API route I have made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmnRJ.png)

The code for that is here:

**pages/projects.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Layout from "../components/Layout";
import Siema from "siema";
import Head from "next/head";
import fetch from "isomorphic-unfetch";

export default class extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.siema = new Siema({
      loop: false
    });
  }

  prev = () => {
    this.siema.prev();
  };

  next = () => {
    this.siema.next();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Layout>
        <Head>
          <title>Jesal Patel ｜ Projects</title>
        </Head>
        <div className="container">
          <section>
            <div className="projects">
              <div className="siema">
                <div>
                  <img src="(ignore this the img is showing on stackoverflow post.)" />
                  <div className="overlay">
                    <div id="overlay_title">Dextero</div>
                    <div id="overlay_description">
                      I developed a multi-touch mobile game for stroke patients
                      to rehabilitate their finger coordination and dexterity.
                    </div>
                    <div id="overlay_tech">Java, Android, LibGDX, SQLite</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div />

              <button onClick={this.prev}>Prev</button>
              <button onClick={this.next}>Next</button>
            </div>
          </section>
        </div>
      </Layout>
    );
  }

  static async getInitialProps({ req }) {
    //This fetch is the reason why my project won't build
    const result = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/projects");
    const projects = await result.json();

    console.log(projects);

    return { projects };
  }
}
```

**The Problem:**

Now the problem begins when I run `next-build` and the following error throws during it: **EDIT: I didn't paste the error properly. NOTE: I run `now-build`script which exports the project and that's my problem, it's what's causing me problems**

```
   I:\Next.js\website>npm run now-build

> website@1.0.0 now-build I:\Next.js\website
> next build && next export -o dist

Creating an optimized production build ...

Compiled successfully.

 ┌ /
 ├ /_app
 ├ /_document
 ├ /_error
 ├ /contact
 └ /projects

> using build directory: I:\Next.js\website\.next
  copying "static" directory
  copying "static build" directory
> No "exportPathMap" found in "next.config.js". Generating map from "./pages"
  launching 11 threads with concurrency of 10 per thread
[====-] 4/5 80% 160/s 0.0s { FetchError: request to http://localhost:3000/api/projects failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (I:\Next.js\website\node_modules\node-fetch\lib\index.js:1444:11)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:392:9)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:82:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:50:3)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
  message:
   'request to http://localhost:3000/api/projects failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000',
  type: 'system',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED' }
{ message:
   'request to http://localhost:3000/api/projects failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000',
  type: 'system',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED' }
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! website@1.0.0 now-build: `next build && next export -o dist`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the website@1.0.0 now-build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Jesal\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-03-19T04_10_45_930Z-debug.log
```

I understand that it's due to this line `const result = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/projects");`, but I don't know what to do to enable it to build. I am new to MEAN stack. I'm not sure if I have to create that route externally somewhere global for it to work fine? I don't know if that will fix it or if it's something else.

I have used Express and Mongoose with this application and the code for these can be found below along with the `package.json` and `next.config.js` files.

**server/index.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const next = require("next");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();
const routes = require("./routes/index.js");
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const dbName = "MySite";
const MONGO_URL =
  "mongodb+srv://admin:<hidden for privacy>@cluster0-5cjs1.mongodb.net/MySite?retryWrites=true";

app
  .prepare()
  .then(() => {
    mongoose.connect(MONGO_URL, { useNewUrlParser: true });

    mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

    mongoose.connection.on("open", function() {
      console.log("mongodb is connected!!");
    });

    const db = mongoose.connection;

    model = db.modelNames();

    db.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "MongoDB connection error:"));

    const server = express();
    server.use(bodyParser.json());
    server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    server.use("/api", routes);

    server.use((req, res, next) => {
      // Also expose the MongoDB database handle so Next.js can access it.
      req.db = db;
      next();
    });

    server.get("*", (req, res) => {
      return handle(req, res);
    });

    server.listen(PORT, () => {
      console.log("Server is up and running on port number " + PORT);
    });
  })
  .catch(ex => {
    console.error(ex.stack);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

**server/routes/index.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

const project_controller = require("../controllers/project_controller");

router.get("/projects", project_controller.projects_list);

module.exports = router;
```

**server/models/project_schema.js**

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var ProjectSchema = new Schema(
  {
    name: String,
    description: String,
    tech: String
  },
  { collection: "project" }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Project", ProjectSchema);
```

**server/controllers/project_controller.js**

```
const Project = require("../models/project_schema");

exports.test = function(req, res) {
  res.send("Greetings from the Test controller!");
};

exports.projects_list = function(req, res) {
  var documents = Project.find({}, function(err, docs) {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.send(docs);
    return docs;
  });
};

exports.project_create = function(req, res) {
  let project = new Project({
    name: req.body.name,
    description: req.body.description,
    tech: req.body.tech
  });

  project.save(function(err, project) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Unsuccessful");
    }
    console.log("Saved!");
  });
};
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "website",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon server/index.js",
    "now-build": "next build && next export -o dist",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start -p 8000"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@engineerapart/nextscript": "^1.0.2",
    "@zeit/next-css": "^1.0.1",
    "@zeit/next-typescript": "^1.1.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "co": "^4.6.0",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "file-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "isomorphic-unfetch": "^3.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "mongodb": "^3.1.13",
    "mongoose": "^5.4.19",
    "next": "^8.0.4-canary.10",
    "next-compose-plugins": "^2.1.1",
    "next-images": "^1.0.4",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.10",
    "react": "^16.8.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.3",
    "react-slick": "^0.23.2",
    "siema": "^1.5.1",
    "superagent": "^4.1.0",
    "url-loader": "^1.1.2"
  }
}
```

**next.config.js**

```
const withCSS = require("@zeit/next-css");
const withImages = require("next-images");
const withPlugins = require("next-compose-plugins");

module.exports = {
  crossOrigin: "anonymous"
};

module.exports = withPlugins([withImages, withCSS]);

module.exports = withImages();

// module.exports = withCSS();

module.exports = {
  target: "serverless"
};

module.exports = withCSS({
  webpack: function(config) {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.(eot|woff|woff2|ttf|svg|png|jpg|gif)$/,
      use: {
        loader: "url-loader",
        options: {
          limit: 100000,
          name: "[name].[ext]"
        }
      }
    });
    return config;
  }
});
```

**UPDATE:** This is an update to Prabhakar Pandey's response, to let you guys know, I always killed the server when running the `now-build`command, Also, to be very clear as I mentioned before on my first edit of this post, that it's the 2nd part of that command which is failing with error, which is `next export -o dist`not `next build`, that works fine!  Also, I'm on Windows OS not Mac OS.

Comment: it's too late, i know, but may be useful for other readers. Cause you fetching localhost -you need to running server at time you build project. So simple open two terminals, in one type `next run dev` to run dev server, then in second console type `next run build` (or your preffer command).

Comment: @northernwind that actually worked for the same problem I am having, no idea why you need npm run dev at the same time

Comment: @MaximeGhéraille Can't figure - you are asking about you issue or about my situation. In case you have same issue - thats because you need to run `_next` server, to operate urls and build pages 'on the fly'.

Answer (score -6):

This happens because you want to run an application on a port which is already being used.

you can check the application running on a port with these commands:

```
For macOS El Capitan and newer (or if your netstat doesn't support -p), use lsof

sudo lsof -i tcp:3000 

For Centos 7 use

netstat -vanp --tcp | grep 3000

Also if wnat to kill any process you can use

kill -9 `PID`

when port is empty you try your application by rebuilding it should work
```

Comment: That wasn't the problem in the first place. I always killed the server when running the `now-build`  command, Note: it's the 2nd part of that command which is failing with error, which is `next export -o dist`.  Also, I'm on Windows